# Treinamento de imagens no tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Boa noite!

Eu estou tentando construir uma rede neural em python utilizando tensorflow e suas demais bibliotecas, minha dúvida e, eu tenho 4 classes e preciso fazer um treinamento delas tenho muitas imagens para cada classe, preciso usar a rede neural CNN já entendo modestamente como ela funciona. Eu precisava programar montar ela em python usando tensorflow alguem algum exemplo? Simples em python pois eu precisava gerar o arquivo dataset ou pb (protoboof) para isso sei que pode levar dias o treinamento em fim minha maior dificuldade e iniciar a programação em python da rede CNN.

Alguem tem algum exemplo? Todos que existe na internet eu vi mas quase miguem tem tutorial ensinando como gerar um arquivo dataset todos os tutoriais ensinam com datasets baixados de websites como ImageNet, Incept, e Mnist. O que eu preciso e de um simples exemplo de como gerar dataset de minhas próprias imagens

Também da Li os videos do  Iris data (classificação de flores) mas ele também trabalha com informações já prontas.

Abraços!

Comment: No caso o problema seria colocar as imagens na array para treino?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar esse modelo com tensorflow-hub (https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/tree/master/examples/image_retraining).
Com esse modelo você pode executar várias manipulações, inclusive incluir um novo dataset.
Basta executá-lo com as linhas de comando
python retrain.py --image_dir "caminho do diretório onde estão suas pastas com imagens"

O algoritmo já vai separar conforme a estrutura das suas pastas, após treinado basta usar um classificados de imagens para testar novas imagens.